# directive unable to retrieve data from a service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have a little SPA using angular. The concept is simple, after login, $routeProvider redirects to a home page where I have a homeController specified.
this is from my home view that is rendered by ng-view while navigating to "/home" :

```
<my-directive datas=getData()></my-directive>
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="data in datas"> {{data.title}} {{data.content}} </li>
</ul>
```

my directive is written as:

```
angular.module('app').directive('myDirective', ['myService', function (myService) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        templateUrl: "partials/my-directive.html",
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.getDatas = function()
            {
                myService.retData();
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

the home controller is:

```
 angular.module('app').controller('homeController', homeController);

homeController.$inject = ['myService', '$scope'];
function homeController(myService, $scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = [];

    initController();

    function initController() {
        vm.data = myService.retData();
    }

}
```

and finally my service is

```
angular.module('app').service('myService', myService);

    function myService () {
        var data = [
                        { id: 1, title: 'Albert Einstein', content: 'Random Content' }
                   ];
        return {
            retData: function () {
                return data;
            },
            addData: function (title, content) {
                var currentIndex = data.length + 1;
                data.push({
                    id: currentIndex,
                    title: title,
                    content: content
                });
            }
        };
    }
```

now that i mentioned everything, here comes the problem. the directive is not able to retrieve data from the service. Actually when i run the project in VS2013, myDirective.js is not even loaded. I included all services, directives, controllers etc in the main HTML page. 
What is causing this problem? 
Does it have something to do with the scope being isolated in the directive? 
What is a better approach to sharing data between a controller, directive and service?
I may have made some silly mistakes while rewriting all the code. Please do point them out, however keep in mind my actual issue and what error may be causing that.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `isolated` scope to pass data controller to directive.

Html:

```
<my-directive datas="getData()" data="data"></my-directive>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('myDirective', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        templateUrl: "partials/my-directive.html",
        link: function (scope) {
          //Here you got the isolated scope data
          var details = scope.data;
        }
    };
}]);
```

**OR**

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/my-directive.html',
        scope: {
            date: '=',
        },
        controller : ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService) {
            myService.retData();
        }],
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            //
        } 
    };
});
```

Comment: that does not work. i want the directive to have access to data from the service. isolating the scope didn't make any difference